# 0x800b0003 while installing .NET Core 1.0.1

Tags: asp.net-core, coreclr

I am trying to install .NET Core 1.0.1, but getting the below error.

> 0x800b0003 - The form specified for the subject is not one supported
>   or known by the specified trust provider.

Please help me to fix this issue.